# Onclick to get another div data value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, pagination

If I click `.page` class, I need to get `data-current` value

```js
$(function() {
  $("#data-total1").on("click", ".page", function() {
    var sliceIdA = $(this).data('current');
    console.log(sliceIdA);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="data-total1" class="slice-pagination" data-current="2" data-total="23">
  <li class="page" data-page="1">1</li>
  <li class="page" data-page="2">2</li>
  <li class="page" data-page="3">3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you need to set it to the .data-total1 li for the click event because thats the value you want

Comment: @KeithI can't able to set that because, I have three sliders dynamically creating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have data-page on the LIs and data-current on the parent UL. Which do you want?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#data-total1").on("click", ".page", function() {
    var sliceIdA = $(this).parent().data('current');
    console.log(sliceIdA, $(this).data("page"));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="data-total1" class="slice-pagination" data-current="2" data-total="23">
  <li class="page" data-page="1">1</li>
  <li class="page" data-page="2">2</li>
  <li class="page" data-page="3">3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the click event to the actual value you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/43zusvts/

```
$(function() {
  $("#data-total1 li").on("click", function() {
      var sliceIdA = $(this).parent().data('current');
  });
})
```

Comment: i want data current value not data page

Comment: Beat you by a minute, Keith